# Background image loading progress track using javaScript

Tags: javascript, html

How can I keep track of background image load progress? I was following [this article](http://blogs.adobe.com/webplatform/2012/01/13/html5-image-progress-events/) and wrote this code below so far.

```js
var progressbar = document.querySelector('#imgload');

var img = document.createElement('img');
img.onloadstart = function(){
 progressbar.innerHTML=0;
};

img.onload = function(){
   document.body.style.backgroundImage='url("High-Res-Wallpaper-HD-For-Desktop.jpg")';
 // img.parentElement.removeChild(img);
};

img.onprogress = function(e){
 if(e.lengthComputable){
  progressbar.innerHTML = e.loaded / e.total * 100;
 }
};

img.onloadend = function(){
 progressbar.innerHTML=100;
};

img.src = 'High-Res-Wallpaper-HD-For-Desktop.jpg';
```

```css
.container{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 900px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Background image load progress</title>
</head>
<body>

 <div class="container">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
 </div>

 <div class='progress'>
  percentage of image load : <span id='imgload'> </span>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But it's not working properly. Progress should show the progress value during the image load.  Can anyone give me some idea how to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by _"its not working properly"_ ?

Comment: `img` element is never appended to `DOM`, how could you remove it ?

Comment: @Rayon I was trying to prevent the memory leak.  Let me fixed that line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought image element have progress events. But it doesn't. According to the article

> The HTML image element lacks progress events. The Web Platform team at
>   Adobe is proposing adding image progress events to HTML5 spec and
>   implementing them in browsers.

So I used his solution to answer my own question.

```
var request;
var progressbar = document.querySelector('#imgload');

function loadImage(imageURI)
{
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onloadstart = showProgressBar;
    request.onprogress = updateProgressBar;
    request.onload = showImage;
    request.onloadend = hideProgressBar;
    request.open("GET", imageURI, true);
    request.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined'); 
    request.send(null);
}

function showProgressBar()
{
    progressbar.innerHTML = 0;
}

function updateProgressBar(e)
{
    if (e.lengthComputable){
        progressbar.innerHTML = e.loaded / e.total * 100;
    }
}

function showImage()
{
    var imageElement = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + base64Encode(request.responseText);
    document.body.style.backgroundImage='url("' + imageElement + '")';
}

function hideProgressBar()
{
    progressbar.innerHTML = 100;
}

// This encoding function is from Philippe Tenenhaus's example at http://www.philten.com/us-xmlhttprequest-image/
function base64Encode(inputStr) 
{
   var b64 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";
   var outputStr = "";
   var i = 0;

   while (i < inputStr.length)
   {
       //all three "& 0xff" added below are there to fix a known bug 
       //with bytes returned by xhr.responseText
       var byte1 = inputStr.charCodeAt(i++) & 0xff;
       var byte2 = inputStr.charCodeAt(i++) & 0xff;
       var byte3 = inputStr.charCodeAt(i++) & 0xff;

       var enc1 = byte1 >> 2;
       var enc2 = ((byte1 & 3) << 4) | (byte2 >> 4);

       var enc3, enc4;
       if (isNaN(byte2))
       {
           enc3 = enc4 = 64;
       }
       else
       {
           enc3 = ((byte2 & 15) << 2) | (byte3 >> 6);
           if (isNaN(byte3))
           {
               enc4 = 64;
           }
           else
           {
               enc4 = byte3 & 63;
           }
       }

       outputStr += b64.charAt(enc1) + b64.charAt(enc2) + b64.charAt(enc3) + b64.charAt(enc4);
    } 

    return outputStr;
}

window.onload = function(){
    loadImage('High-Res-Wallpaper-HD-For-Desktop.jpg');
}
```